# How to get input from a JOptionPane option being clicked. - java

Tags: java, jscrollpane, joptionpane

[image: JOptionPane]

How can I get input from the options being clicked on the `JOptionPane`, not the `Okay` button but the options I've provided such as `Emerald`, `Autumn` etc.

Here's my code

```
public static ArrayList<String> Skins = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void skinJPanel() {
    try {
        String[] skins = {"Emerald", "Autumn", "Black Steel", "Blue Steel", "Creme Coffee", "Green Magic"};
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            Skins.add(skins[i]);
        }
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(200, 200);
        JList list = new JList(Skins.toArray());
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollpane = new JScrollPane(list);
        panel.add(scrollpane);
        scrollpane.getViewport().add(list);
        String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, scrollpane, "Aftermath Skin Chooser", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println(string);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Skins.clear();
}
```

Comment: So, I assume you don't want to wait for the user to click [Okay]/[Cancel], or do you just want to get the selected value from the `JList`?

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value AFTER the user has pressed [Okay], you should probably do something more like...

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, scrollpane, "Aftermath Skin Chooser", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    String value = (String) list.getSelectedValue();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Worked absolutely perfectly, thank you for taking the time now I know what to do when faced with this situation again :)

Comment: Glad it could help ;) ps- Like the look and feel ;)